# CSS - Writing classes the right way

Tags: html, css

I guess this is quite simple, although I can't seem to wrap my head around why my CSS code doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
.box{
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
.box .warning{
    background: #FFF7F2;
    border: 1px solid #ffefe5;
}

<div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="box warning">dfda</div>
</div>
```

And a fiddle to show it in action..

http://jsfiddle.net/91b21z8k/

**My problem is, why doesn't the `<div>` have the `.warning` class assigned to it?

Comment: It should be `.box.warning` because both the classes are on the same element. `.box .warning` means an element with `class='warning'` which is the child of another element with `class='box'`.

Comment: OR may be write `<div class="col-xs-4 box">`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't give the space after the .box selector because it's in the same class:

```
.box.warning{
    background: #FFF7F2;
    border: 1px solid #ffefe5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you make `.box .warning` you're referring to a son with the class "box" of an element with the class "warning". It's never going to work.

If you did `.col-xs-4 .warning`, you'd have the style applied

Doc about selectors and how to apply them:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

### Update

check @C-link Nepal answer to get the last point (if you have to accept an answer, he gave the right answer first, XD): Removing the space between classes makes styles only applied to elements which will have all the classes present on the rule:

About the classes selector: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html

#### Examples

To paint in red the paragraph:

```
<div class="perry">
    <p class="mason">Hi</p>
</div>

.perry .mason {
    color: red;
}
```

---

```
<div>
   <p class="perry mason">Hi</p>
</div>

.perry.mason {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because including a space in the definition means the selector will target `.warning` elements which are children of `.box`; not `.box` elements which also have a class of `.warning`.

To target the `<div class="box warning"></div>`, simply remove the space in your selector's name:

```
.box.warning{
    background: #FFF7F2;
    border: 1px solid #ffefe5;
}
```

[**Please see this updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/91b21z8k/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove space like this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/91b21z8k/2/)**

```
.box.warning{
    background: #FFF7F2;
    border: 1px solid #ffefe5;
}
```

Or simply write **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/91b21z8k/4/)**

```
.warning{
    background: #FFF7F2;
    border: 1px solid #ffefe5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want style div **nested into div.box** then write

```
<div class="col-xs-4 box">
    <div class="warning">dfda</div>
</div>
```

Space between classes in CSS means hierarchy of elements defined by selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spase between two class names

```
.box{
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
.box.warning{
    background: #FFF7F2;
    border: 1px solid #ffefe5;
}
```

Here's [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/91b21z8k/7/)!